# Eclipse, POM.XML can't edit derived File

Tags: json, rest, maven, jersey, jax-rs

I'm creating a webservice API for my internship project, I'm using JAX-RS ( maven + jersey 2.26).

But when I'm editing my POM.XML file, it says that it's a derived file, and when I save my edit it returns to the same code it was.

Help me fix it please.

[As you can see, here's the code I need to edit, and the POM.XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rta9K.png)

Thank youu

Comment: The pom file you can change is *NOT* in the `target` directory cause there are all artifacts which have been compiled/packaged etc. so do not try to change something in `target` directory as Eclipse told you...

Comment: Thank you my friend for your answer, so how can I do to enable the use of JSON?

Comment: You need to change your pom file under the "Deployed Resources" ...

Comment: Thank you my friend, but it's edited but an error occured :/
"The managed version is 2.26 The artifact is managed in org.glassfish.jersey:jersey-bom:2.26". Thank you for the time you spent with me.